# how to make a percentage height div responsive to content inside 100vh section

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

morning all,
thought this one would be straight forward but not (unless I'm missing something obvious)

[EDIT] The Layout of the front-page section has to match the front cover of a book that has a yellow stripe 28% of the height of the book, 60% down the page [/EDIT]

I have a section that I want 100vh within that section I have two divs set to percentage height, each with content.  It all looks great until I reduce the screen size.  How can I have a percentage height div and keep it responsive to the content (apart from using media queries).  Note, I'm using flex to position the content within the divs.

[EDIT] In other words (if necessary) increase the height of the 60% `.intro` div and the 28% `.stripe` div to accommodate the text wrapping

I've tried playing with using `min-height:28%;` on the .stripe class but that then breaks the constraints of the image height being 80% of the .stripe height.  Can anyone help please.

```css
.fs {
  height: 100vh;
}
.container {
  margin:0;
  background-color:#545454;
  overflow: auto;
}
.intro {
  height:60%;
}
.bees-intro {
  font-size:60px;
  color:#f4d00b;
  text-align:center;
}
.stripe {
  height:28%; 
  background-color:#f4d00b; 
  color:#000000;
}
.bee-quest {
  font-size:80px;
  margin-right:0px;
  height:100%;
  margin-right:40px;
}
.bee-quest img {
  margin-right:20px;
  height:80%;
}
.align-center-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}
.align-right-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<section id="front-page">
  <div class="fs container">
    <div class="intro align-center-center">
      <h1 class="bees-intro">The Bees of Greater Manchester</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="stripe">
      <div class="bee-quest align-right-center">
        <img src="bee-quest.png">
        <span class="">QUEST</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

A working pen can be seen [HERE](https://codepen.io/butlerps/pen/WXrwLE)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by it's not responsive but i'm guessing you want the yellow box to wrap around the bee logo and text when it's in mobile? To do this, remove the 28% height from the `stripe` and and use the content within it to determine the height.

Example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/m3fnp0nL/

Let me know if this isn't what you're after :)

Comment: Hey Shaun, thanks for that. I can see how you've achieved it by removing the 28% height  from the `stripe` and adding a max-height to the image class to control the height of the stripe.  How could I achieve the same with the `.intro`.  I've updated the question to make it a bit clearer, as percentages are quite specific

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Shaun I've figured out a good solution

The `.stripe` is set to `min-height: 28vh;`  and the image is set to `height: calc(28vh - 20px);`

I've set the `.intro` to `min-height:60vh` so as the wrapping text will increase the container size.

```
.fs {
  height: 100vh;
}
.container {
  margin:0;
  background-color:#545454;
  overflow: auto;
}
.intro {
  min-height:60vh;
}
.bees-intro {
  font-size:60px;
  color:#f4d00b;
  text-align:center;
}
.stripe{
  background-color:#f4d00b; 
  color:#000000;
  min-height:28vh;
}
.bee-quest {
  font-size:80px;
  margin:10px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}
.bee-quest img {
  height: calc(28vh - 20px);
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bee-quest img {
    margin-right:20px;  
  }
  .bee-quest span {
    margin-right:20px;  
  }
}
.align-center-center {
   display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.align-right-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


<section id="front-page">
  <div class="fs container">
  <div class="intro align-center-center">
    <h1 class="bees-intro">The Bees of Greater Manchester</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="stripe align-right-center">
    <div class="bee-quest">
      <img src="http://www.beequest.co.uk/images/bee-quest.png">
      <span class="">QUEST</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The original Pen has been updated with the correct answer

The only problem I have now is that the content scrolls within the divs